# DEM ASIL components configuration

Tags: autosar

I want to configure DEM storage and enable condition for ASIL components can anybody help how I can configure this

I am trying connecting DEM Satalite to ASIL task in os and connecting to ASIL application components so here I can able to get set event status call like Rte_call_dtcname(event id, argum1) here event ID is fixed because in DEM Satalite the event id type ports are already created so I am just connecting that port to application components, so now I want to know how to configure the storage condition and enable condition for this ASIL components

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the EnableConditions and StorageConditions usually in the Dem.

Dem provides certain standard interfaces (see also SWS Dem chapter 8.6 Service Interfaces).

Your tool should then also provide in the generated Dem ServiceSwComponent ports for each storage/enable condition, where a "Port defined argument" already defines to according Storage/EnableConditionId.

Your SWC then needs R-Ports with the Dem interfaces:

- pDemEnCnd_1 - RequiredInterfaceType=EnableCondition
- pDemEnCnd_2 - RequiredInterfaceType=EnableCondition
- pDemStCnd_1 - RequiredInterfaceType=StorageCondition
- pDemStCnd_2 - RequiredInterfaceType=StorageCondition

You should then also add to your SWC SeviceDependencies / ServiceNeeds (see TPS SoftwareComponentTemplate ch. 13.8.3.4 and ch. 13.8.3.5)

After adding the PortAccess in your runnable, you should then be able to call:

```
void MyRunnable(void) {
    boolean bEnCnd1 = TRUE;
    boolean bStCnd1 = TRUE;
    // determine conditions
    // ...
    // now call 
    Rte_Call_pDemEnCnd_1_SetEnableCondition(bEnCnd1);
    Rte_Call_pDemStCnd_1_SetStorageCondition(bStCnd1);
}
```